# Помогите с "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position "

Tags: javascript, синтаксис

```
_log: function(e) {
  var t = this.$element.attr("id");
  t && (e = '"' + t + '": ' + e),
  e = "bootstrap-fileinput: " + e,
  void 0 !== window.console.log ? window.console.log(e) : window.alert(e)
```

Я не очень разбираюсь. Возникает ошибка при загрузке изображений

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

В консоли chrome указывает на эту строку - `void 0 !== window.console.log ? window.console.log(e) : window.alert(e)`

Помогите разобраться что не так? До этого все работало.

Comment: Вряд ли в этой строчке возникает эта ошибка. "До этого все работало." - до чего, до этого?

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас где-то вызывается `JSON.parse` и в него передается результат ajax запроса. А в результате вернулся не JSON, а HTML

Comment: Ошибка не в этой строке, указывает на нее только потому что это враппер над логгером. Приведите пожалуйста полую цепь ошибки и какие изменения вы внесли что начала появлятся данная ошибка?